# Custom Error Messages in Azure Pipelines for Failed Tasks

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

For logging custom error messages the [Azure Pipeline documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell) suggest the following logging commands (PowerShell):

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
exit 1
```

However, in the pipeline's summary (and the e-mail notification) I only see the - rather unspecific - PowerShell error:

[image]

So how can I get the error *Something went very wrong* in the summary **and** fail the task (which is a PowerShell script)?

Comment: Isn't it logged as expected when you check the logs on the web prompt?

Comment: It is logged but the summary or the mail notification give no hint about the real cause. The exit condition is just '1'. I want to make it clear in the pipeline's summary why it failed without having to analyze the logs.

Comment: Not sure whether what you want is possible out of the box, however, have you thought about creating an additional tab in your pipeline to summarize all the errors you get? (Might be a little bit overwhelming, but it should work) There are tasks better saying extensions which allows you to publish html results, you could generate one yourselff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, `##vso[task.logissue type=error]` worked as expected and created a new error box, but it was always followed by this exit code error.

To make the task fail with a custom error message, I used the following:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed]"
exit 0
```